# Remove items from list based on another, w.r.t. positions

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<int>`s, e.g.:

```
L1 = (new int[]{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1}).ToList();
L2 = (new int[]{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}).ToList();
```

Now, if I want to remove a, b, c, g, h, i; because their correspondent on L1 is 1, what should be the LINQ for that?

I can get indexes in L1 with:

```
var L1IDX = L1.Select((it, id) => new { itm = it, idx = id })
              .Where(l => l.itm == 1)
              .Select(l => l.idx);
```

But then what? I can't find a `Remove...()` that takes a list of indices.

Comment: L2 is not a List<int>

Comment: it is if a..f are defined as int variables before :)

Comment: Yeah that makes it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<int> L1 = new List<int>() {1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1};
List<char> L2 = new List<char>() {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'};
var result = L1.Zip(L2, (i, c) => new
            {
                I = i,
                C = c
            })
            .Where(x => x.I != 1)
            .Select(x => x.C)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Correct except that it should be x.I != 1, no?

Answer (score 4):

There is no overload that takes a list of indexes, but there is a method for a single index, `RemoveAt`.  You need to call that in a loop:

```
foreach(var index in L1IDX.OrderByDescending(x=>x))
    L2.RemoveAt(index);
```

If you find yourself wanting to remove a number of items by index often, you may find it worthwhile to use an extension method to remove all of a sequence of indecies from a list; it'll basically look just like the above, wrapped in a method:

```
public static void RemoveAllAt<T>(this IList<T> list,
    IEnumerable<int> indecies)
{
    foreach (var index in indecies.OrderByDescending(x => x))
        list.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to break because after you call `RemoveAt(index)` for `index = 0` then all the indexes are going to shift over one spot?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal True, need to make sure you go from the end to the start.  I suppose technically you could get by just calling `Reverse`, but this adds a bit more clarity in my opinion.

Comment: Oh hey, that's a clever solution. I was going to do something far more complicated but no more effective. +1 for a solution that I wouldn't have to read docs to understand (cough `Zip` cough).

Comment: Interestingly :) Two upvotes on obviously wrong answer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan In what way does it not work?  Note for the record that your answer doesn't technically answer the question, which asks to remove the items from the list, not create a new list with the items that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm pretty sure it works after the edit. It was wrong before, and it didn't have my upvote then.

Comment: From OP "Now, if I want to remove a, b, c, g, h, i; because their correspondent on L1 is 1".

Comment: @HamletHakobyan L1IDX is a list that was produced by `L1.Where(x => x == 1).Select(x => indexof(x)).ToList()` or something to that effect. That's supposed to be implied

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yeah.  And your point?  The OP already created a query that generates a sequence of integers representing the indecies to remove.  I showed him how to use that query to remove the items at those indecies.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Sure, it's an entirely reasonable thing to do.

Comment: What about performance? By the way, using `Reverse` instead of `OrderByDescending` more reasonable IMO.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I specifically mentioned in a that it would be more performant, but only marginally so, and that I feel that the improved clarity of `OrderBy` is worthwhile, unless there is some performance testing that would indicate it's enough of a win.

Answer (score 2):

At first you can't modify the list using LINQ. You can create new list with required values.

```
var query = L1.Zip(L2, (f, s) => new {F = f, S = s})
            .Where(f => f.F != 1).Select(r => r.S);
```

Comment: He gave no indication that the items should be removed using LINQ.  You [can] use LINQ to find the indecies to be removed, and then you use non-LINQ code to remove them.  That's entirely reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

Using this, **you don't have to create a new sequence altogether.**

```
var L1 = (new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 }).ToList();
var L2 = (new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' }).ToList();
int index = 0;
L2.RemoveAll(delegate(char c) {
   bool IsRemove = false;
   if (L1[index] == 1)
   {
     IsRemove = true;
   }
   else
   {
     IsRemove = false;
   }
   index++;
   return IsRemove;
});
```